# How to detect if a function called fopen or not?

Tags: elf

I'm trying to write a pam backdoor scanner, which may call fopen function in pam_sm_authenticate(normal file will not call fopen in this function) to store username and password, but I can't use external command such as "nm, readelf" or something like that, so the only way seems to scan pam_sm_authenticate function and find all call instructions and caculate the address to check if it is calling fopen, but it is too troublesome and i'm not very familiar with ELF file(I even dont know how to find offset of pam_sm_authenticate, I'm useing dlopen and dlsym to get the address..), so I wonder if there is a better or easy way to detect it? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: building a robust "pam backdoor scanner" is theoretically impossible, so you should give up now and think about other ways to solve your problem.

Your question is very confusing, but I *think* what you are asking is: "can I determine programmatically whether `pam_sm_authenticate` calls `fopen`".

That is the *wrong* question to ask, for several reasons:

- if `pam_sm_authenticate` calls `foo`, and `foo` calls `fopen`, then you still have a problem, so you really should be scanning `pam_sm_authenticate` *and* every function it calls (recursively),
- the `fopen` is *far* from the only way to write files: you could also use `open`, or `system` (as in `system("echo $secret > /tmp/backdoor")`, or direct `sys_open` syscall, or a multitude of other hacks.
- finally, the `pam_sm_authenticate` can use [just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques to build arbitrary code (including code calling `fopen`) at runtime, and answering whether it does by examining its code is equivalent to solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) (i.e. impossible).

Comment: Your program could as well `dlsym()` the functions or looking them up directly in the process by iterating over the ELF symbol tables, etc.